# Pregunta KeyListener como puedo mandar los eventos a otra clace

Tags: java

```
package prueba;  
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Ventana extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

    int codigo;

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Ventana(){
        addKeyListener(this);
        System.out.println("Tecla Johnn"+codigo);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        codigo=e.getKeyCode();
        if(codigo == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            System.out.println(codigo);
            //animar(x,y,getCodigo());
            setCodigo(codigo);
        }
        else if(codigo == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            System.out.println("Right");
            System.out.println(codigo);
            setCodigo(codigo);
        }
        else if(codigo == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            System.out.println("Up");
            System.out.println(codigo);
            setCodigo(codigo);
        }
        else if(codigo == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            System.out.println("Down");
            System.out.println(codigo);
            setCodigo(codigo);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        //int codigo=e.getKeyCode();
        //System.out.println("Hola"+codigo);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }   
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con mandar los eventos a otra clase? Explica un poco lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Tengo otra clase donde dibujo un cuadrado con drawRect() quiero animar ese cuadrado por teclado, es por eso que necesito relacionar ambas clases para para poder animar el cuadrado.

Comment: Hola Johnn Hidalgo, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Debes editar tu pregunta para añadir una descripción de lo que hace el código, lo que esperas recibir y el resultado que obtienes en su lugar, así como de los mensajes de error o dificultades que te estés encontrando. Lee [ask] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y cómo funciona en general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes una clase llamada `ManejadorEventos` y que quieres manipular en esta los eventos que se generan en la clase `Ventana`. Primero debes tener en la clase `ManejadorEventos` métodos que reciban como parámetros objetos del tipo de evento que manejará.

```
public class ManejadorEventos {
    public void manejarEventoTeclado(KeyEvent event) {
        // aquí irá el código necesario
    }
}
```

Luego debes tener una instancia de esta clase en la clase `Ventana` e invocar los métodos que quieras pasándoles los objetos de eventos.

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    ManejadorEventos manejador = new ManejadorEventos();

    // Otros atributos

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        manejador.manejarEventoTeclado(e);
    }

    // Otros métodos
}
```

Nota que he creado la instancia de la clase manejadora de eventos en la misma declaración del atributo, pero podrías pasar la instancia correcta utilizando el constructor de la clase `Ventana`.

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que  son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real. Lee [answer] para más información.